# Setup Git on server

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to understand how Jenkins works with Git when you want to have Continuous Integration.
Do you have a bare repository or do you have a normal repo on the Jenkins server?
I think it makes sense that the repo is bare, because you push stuff to it and it must not become corrupted, but how do you get all the files when you want to deploy the project? Do you use git archive or git clone?
I'm learning about git hooks and I made a dummy repo in a folder on my laptop. I want to modify the update hook to start a file called index.html from the project, but if the project is bare, I can't access it. And I understand that it's not ok to have a normal repository on a server.

Thank you!

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once.

Comment: It's actually one question, how does Git work on a server for CI?
The other questions are just my theories.

Comment: Then you should probably reword your question. I count three question marks and at least three guesses about how this might work. If you want to get good results, spend some time to make sure that your question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have a separate jenkins server and a separate repository server.

If you set up a job with git as scm then you need to configure the remote repository path in the job configuration. The Jenkins git plugin will clone the given repository a a local folder under the jenkins home directory.